# Get all the data rows that include specific time regardless of day, month,year

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, time, grouping

I have a dataset that looks like that:

```
                          A   B     C        
    Full Date                                              
    2018-11-01 22:00:45  19  A1  2004.123711
    2018-11-01 22:15:00  19  F3  2000.000000
    2018-11-01 22:30:00  19  A1  2032.000000
    2018-11-01 22:45:00  19  N3  2038.264739
    2018-11-01 23:00:00  19  M33 2044.000000
    .
    .
    .                                            
    2019-11-29 23:45:00  169  T4  2156.000000
    2019-11-29 23:45:00   98  C3  6010.678532
    2019-11-29 23:45:00   87  B5  142.574257
    2019-11-29 23:45:00  186  E21 2256.818182
    2019-11-29 23:45:00   62  F40 1976.878613
```

I am trying to group the data so that I will get the whole data set only including with the time stamp:
00:00:00 ( the year and month don't matter). I have used groupby(data.index.time) but that dosent give me what I want.

I was thinking if I could use a for loop, but I not sure how to get the whole row of data not just a specific value as I have used before on dataframe.

I was thinking to date index and split it into 'date' and 'time' columns and then:

```
for in range(len(data)):
    if(data[loc[i,'time'] == '00:00:00']:
        df.append(i)
```

There are 2 problems with that approach. 1) the 'time' column is an dtype of object 2) df.append(i) does not get the entire row.

Im not sure how to do this properly, grouping by specific time.
The data set I want is:

```
                          A   B     C        
    Full Date                                              
    2018-11-01 00:00:00  1   F1  2004.123711
    2018-12-10 00:00:00  3   F3  2000.000000
    2019-01-15 00:00:00  2   A3  2032.000000
    2019-06-21 00:00:00  1   N3  2038.264739
    2018-10-29 00:00:00  21  M3  2044.000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `datetime.time`:

```
import datetime
# Sample data
            Full Date   A    B            C
0 2018-11-01 22:00:45  19   A1  2004.123711
1 2018-11-01 22:15:00  19   F3  2000.000000
2 2018-11-01 00:00:00  19   A1  2032.000000
3 2018-11-01 22:45:00  19   N3  2038.264739
4 2018-11-01 23:00:00  19  M33  2044.000000

new_df = df[df["Full Date"].dt.time.eq(datetime.time(0, 0))]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   Full Date   A   B       C
2 2018-11-01  19  A1  2032.0
```

Comment: Thank you Chris! That is exactly that I want !